# Aggregating PowerQuery Table directly in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a PowerQuery table which holds a history of products sold and would like to aggregate on several dimensions.
It is possible to accomplish this with PivotTables or with separate queries and I know how to do that, but was wondering if its possible to do it directly with a function in a cell?
The reason is to have a clean dashboard in Excel with the most relevant statistics.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can do this with PowerPivot, and CUBEVALUE functions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Query, select the columns you want to group on and hit the **Group By** button.  In the pop-up window, specify the Aggregations you need e.g. Sum, Count etc. Note you often need the **Advanced** view of the **Group By** pop-up.